# Websphere portal very slow to start up

Tags: rad, websphere-portal

When I start up the WebSphere portal application through RAD, I see there are a ton of portlets that start up like this:

```
[18/01/13 14:26:09:980 EST] 0000000f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: PA_Banner_Ad
[18/01/13 14:26:10:637 EST] 0000000f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: PA_Banner_Ad
[18/01/13 14:26:10:652 EST] 0000000f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: PA_Bookmarks
[18/01/13 14:26:11:215 EST] 0000000f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: PA_Bookmarks
[18/01/13 14:26:11:215 EST] 0000000f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: PA_SQL_Query
```

Now there are a lot of these kind of portlets. Is there a way to load a minimum # of default portlets? Because this makes the portal server startup very very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Portal Server 6.1 or later, enable lazy loading of portlets.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27015437

Comment: i did the configuration mentioned for windows. It seems this configuration change only affects portlets created by me. The websphere internal portlets that i did not create or deploy are still loaded at startup, making it slow. But thank you for a useful link